# Efficient method to multiply floating point matrix with binary matrix and get double precision results

Tags: matrix, fortran

I have a matrix `A` which is of size `(n2, n1)` and I am multiplying it by a matrix, `B`, of size `(n1, n0)`. I have identified this single matrix multiplication as the bottleneck in my `Fortran` code. Out of ~2000 lines of code, this single line takes about 77% of the runtime.

`A` is a double precision matrix with floating point values. `B` is, currently, a double precision matrix containing only values `1.0` and `0.0`. I can easily make this integer, or even binary, but I was using it as `real` so that I could preserver precision in `matmul(A,B)`.

What is a better way to perform this matrix multiplication to cut down on runtime?

Before anyone suggests it, I am using `DGEMM` and compiling with `-O3` and `-mavx` for `gfortran`, and `-O3` with `-xhost` on `ifort`.

The largest data I have implemented this program on so far, `N = 5000`, results in `n2 = 1668`, `n1 = 1701`, and `n0 = 1631`. This algorithm was implemented in `Matlab` and has shorter runtime. Matlab version is about 2.5 seconds, while this fortran program is about 7 seconds. Since this single matrix multiplication is so large, I'm thinking that Matlab is doing something interesting with the variable types.

I have compiled this with `ifort` using `MKL` and am current linking against `-lblas` and using `-fexternal-blas`, relying on `matmul` to perform the underlying `BLAS` routines. The result of `ldd` on my binary executable is:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaacb000)
liblapack.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/liblapack.so.3 (0x00002aaaaaccd000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3 (0x00002aaaab4f0000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00002aaaab747000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002aaaaba39000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003f78c00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaabcbe000)
libf77blas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/libf77blas.so.3 (0x00002aaaac052000)
libcblas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.so.3 (0x00002aaaac272000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
libatlas.so.3 => /usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.so.3 (0x00002aaaac492000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002aaaacaee000)
```

`B` is structured in the way that it has zeros and ones. The lower left portion (not truly lower triangular) has ones and the upper right portion (not triangular) is zeros.

It appears that the Matlab code is treating the `B` matrix as `logical`.

Comment: The right way to link to the MKL these days with ifort is to use `-mkl`. `-lblas` may find a system library that is not optimized.

Comment: I only use -lblas when compiling with gfortran. I use specific Intel compilation flags when linking with ifort

Comment: a) you can use those same options with `gfortran` to get the MKL, and b) you might try -mkl with `ifort` just to be sure.

Comment: I don't see how using real for the integer matrix would give you better precision. You can check for your BLAS using ldd on the binary you compile.

Comment: Your latest edit shows you are actually not linking against the MKL, but rather against ATLAS (which I'd personally drop any time in favour of OpenBLAS). You may try to leave out `-lblas` in linking.

Answer (score 1):

What is the percentage of nonzero entries in $B$?  If a high percentage of the entries are 0's, then you might well be better off treating $B$ as a sparse matrix in the multiplication.

You haven't told us the size of the matrices.  What are n0 and n1?  Or at least their order of magnitude?

You haven't said what implementation of the BLAS you're currently using.  Your specific comments about compilation flags suggest that you might be using the reference BLAS implementation, which would be a very poor choice in comparison with optimized cache-aware and multithreaded implementations of the BLAS routines such as ATLAS, OpenBLAS, ACML, and MKL.

Comment: Will update ...

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the MKL blas routines multithreaded?  What is your setting of OMP_NUM_THREADS?

Comment: I am intentionally running this singlethreaded. This program is to be used for high throughput systems and is to be run millions of times, so spending theads on sub linear speed up would not be efficient. I am comparing this to singlethreaded matlab, though, so I believe it can be spedup.

Comment: Are you sure that MATLAB is running single threaded?  It's kind of difficult to turn off the multithreading in the MATLAB blas...

Comment: I'm sure. I launch it from command line with the single computation thread flag and watch the cpu usage.

Comment: And your sure that you've done the same number of multiplications in the MATLAB code and the Fortran code?  Can you strip this down to a much smaller example that shows the same performance difference between the MKL blas and the blas used by MATLAB?  Have you checked to see what version of blas your MATLAB is using?

Comment: Back to an earlier question, what is the percentage of nonzeros in your B matrix?  Does it vary over the course of the run?  Is MATLAB storing B as a sparse matrix (or as anything other than a regular dense matrix of doubles)?